# Are ACLs for share points in OS X 10.6 fixed

Tags: mac-osx, network-share, afp, osx-snow-leopard

Share points are 'broken' in OS X 10.5 in that inherited write permissions always take precedence over ACLs at the sharepoint itself.

[OS X AFP shares and access](https://serverfault.com/questions/39976/os-x-afp-shares-and-access)

Does anybody know if this is fixed in 10.6?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a somewhat different set up (samba share on solaris using ZFS NFSv4 ACLs extensively), and the finder bugs I was getting in 10.5 have not been fixed in 10.6.

Very annoying.